# How to transform 2D tuple [x][y] to [y][x] and call variadic function for each result set

Tags: c++, lambda, tuples, c++20, variadic-functions

I want to "rotate" the axis of a 2D tuple and call a variadic function for each of the result sets.

All tuple elements have the same type, but the element items/attributes might have different type.

Starting from

```
constexpr auto someData = std::make_tuple(
    std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3.0),
    std::make_tuple(4, 5, 6.0),
    std::make_tuple(7, 8, 9.0));
```

the result I want to achieve, are calls to a variadic function like this

```
 someFunction(1, 4, 7);
 someFunction(2, 5, 8);
 someFunction(3.0, 6.0, 9.0);
```

I was trying to solve this using `std::get<index>(tuple)` in a `lambda` to create indices using `std::make_index_sequence` and invoke a variadic function, passing tuple elements via `std::apply`, like this (without success).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
constexpr auto someFunction(auto&&... args) {
    //do some stuff
    ((std::cout << args),...);
}
int main() {
    constexpr auto someData = std::make_tuple(
        std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3.0),
        std::make_tuple(4, 5, 6.0),
        std::make_tuple(7, 8, 9.0)
    );

    // want to get
    // someFunction(1, 4, 7);
    // someFunction(2, 5, 8);
    // someFunction(3.0, 6.0, 9.0);

    using t0_t = typename std::tuple_element<0, decltype(someData)>::type;
    [] <std::size_t... I> (auto&& tuple, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        ([&] (std::size_t i) {
            std::apply([&](auto&&... args) {
                //(std::get<i>(args), ...);
                // someFunction ((std::get<i>(args), ...));
            }, tuple);
        }(I), ...);
    }(std::forward<decltype(someData)>(someData),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<t0_t>::value>{});
}
```

How can that be done correctly?

Comment: It surely can be done but it will be horrible because you have to transpose the types between the inner and outer tupples. Are you sure you need a Matrix that holds elements of different types in the same Matrix? It's not just all supposed to be `double` or all supposed to be `std::complex<double>` or so?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow You are right, the term ```matrix``` might not be exactly precise, since the element attributes might have different types. I have added a comment in the question. Technically this would be handled by ```someFunction```, where all arguments would be of same type. Maybe the terms table / records / columns would fit better for that case.

Comment: Call it a 2D tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested lambdas, one to expand the index and one to expand the `tuple`

```
constexpr auto someData = std::make_tuple(
  std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3.0),
  std::make_tuple(4, 5, 6.0),
  std::make_tuple(7, 8, 9.0)
);

// someFunction(1, 4, 7);
// someFunction(2, 5, 8);
// someFunction(3.0, 6.0, 9.0);

std::apply([](auto first_tuple, auto... rest_tuples) {
  [&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    ([]<size_t N>(auto... tuples) {
      someFunction(std::get<N>(tuples)...);
    }.template operator()<I>(first_tuple, rest_tuples...), ...);
  }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(first_tuple)>>{});
}, someData);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sdq5rMfWj)

Comment: Any idea why this does not compile with ```MSVC```?

Comment: Bug. The [workaround](https://godbolt.org/z/hz5YY46c8) is to define the inner lambda outside.

Comment: I found another workaround keeping the code compact in case of having the same issue in MSVC. Modifying ```[]<size_t N>(auto... tuples)``` to ```[]<size_t N, typename... Tuples>(Tuples... tuples)``` to avoid the ```auto``` parameter declaration of innermost Lambda worked for me.